# Make: "nothing to be done for target" when invoking two phony targets at once

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Simple makefile:

```
.PHONY:\
gitbranch-foo
gitbranch-foo: dir=./foo
gitbranch-foo: git-spawn-branch

.PHONY:\
gitbranch-bar
gitbranch-bar: dir=./bar
gitbranch-bar: git-spawn-branch

.PHONY:\
git-spawn-branch
git-spawn-branch:
    @$(call  git_branch,$(dir),$(branch))
    @echo > /dev/null

define git_branch
    cd $(1);                                         \
    git checkout -b   $(2)            || true;       \
    git push     -u   origin     $(2) || true;
endef
```

Invoking two rules at once:

```
make gitbranch-foo gitbranch-bar branch=something/blah/blah  -rRd
```

As you can see 'foo' repo switches successfully but 'bar' repo is not even being processed by make. Why?

```
Switched to a new branch 'something/blah/blah'  <-- 'foo' switches successfully
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for something/blah/blah:
remote:   ....
remote:
To xyz.net:foo
 * [new branch]      master -> something/blah/blah
Branch 'something/blah/blah' set up to track remote branch 'something/blah/blah' from 'origin'.

make: Nothing to be done for 'gitbranch-bar'. <-------- 'bar' is not even processed   why?
```

The debugging output of 'make' looks like so:

```
Branch 'something/blah/blah' set up to track remote branch 'something/blah/blah' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
Reaping winning child 0x563e010f42d0 PID 2092 
Live child 0x563e010f42d0 (git-spawn-branch) PID 2096
Reaping winning child 0x563e010f42d0 PID 2096
Removing child 0x563e010f42d0 PID 2096 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file 'git-spawn-branch'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'gitbranch-foo'.
Must remake target 'gitbranch-foo'.
Successfully remade target file 'gitbranch-foo'.
Considering target file 'gitbranch-bar'.
 File 'gitbranch-bar' does not exist.
  Pruning file 'git-spawn-branch'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'gitbranch-bar'.
Must remake target 'gitbranch-bar'.
Successfully remade target file 'gitbranch-bar'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'gitbranch-bar'.
```

Can't make heads or tails out of it though. Any insight as to why 'make' behaves this way is appreciated.

Note: I'm aware I can refactor the makefile a bit like below to get it to do my bidding - I just want to understand why the original approach didn't work as intended

```
.PHONY:\
gitbranch-foo
gitbranch-foo:
    @$(call  git_branch,./foo,$(branch))
    @echo > /dev/null

.PHONY:\
gitbranch-bar
gitbranch-bar:
    @$(call  git_branch,./bar,$(branch))
    @echo > /dev/null

define git_branch
    cd $(1);                                         \
    git checkout -b   $(2)            || true;       \
    git push     -u   origin     $(2) || true;
endef
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is strictly due to `make`'s rules and has nothing to do with any of the other tags here (I'll remove all the others).  The makefile that doesn't work says:

- to build `gitbranch-foo`, we must build `git-spawn-branch`
- to build `gitbranch-bar`, we must build `git-spawn-branch`

(plus of course the code for building `git-spawn-branch` itself and the other associated stuff, but let's stop here).

You then *run* make, telling it to build both `gitbranch-foo` and `gitbranch-bar`.

Make picks one of these to build—`gitbranch-foo`, in this case—and begins building.  *Oh hey*, says make to itself, *this needs `git-spawn-branch` to be built, and we have not done that yet*.  Off goes make, which builds `git-spawn-branch` according to the rules.  Now it's built!  Make can go back to building `gitbranch-foo`.  This executes the remaining recipe, which is empty.

If parallel builds are allowed, `make` can also now begin building `gitbranch-bar` while `gitbranch-foo` builds.  If not, we wait for `gitbranch-foo` to be fully built at this point.  Either way we very quickly get around to buildling `gitbranch-bar`.  *Hm,* says make to itself, *this needs `git-spawn-branch` to be built ... but fortunately, I have done that already! Onward! Let's make the rest of `gitbranch-bar` now!*  That requires executing the empty recipe, which goes very quickly.

Make is now done.  It has built everything required.

(The makefile that works uses `$call` sensibly, directly from each rule, so that the commands that `$call` expands to are required to be run for each target, rather than hidden away in a third target that can be built just once and never needs to be run any further.)

(Note that the gmake documentation mentions that a `.PHONY` rule is run every time.  This means *once per invocation of `make`*, not *once per invocation of the rule*.)

Comment: +100 -> "Note that the gmake documentation mentions that a .PHONY rule is run every time. This means once per invocation of make, not once per invocation of the rule" ooohh that makes it crystal clear now!